# Sass (scss) function with extra NON-variable

Tags: sass

I work on Sass/Webpack page and found this piece:

```
    @mixin below($size) {
      @include breakpoint($size down) {
        @content
      }
    }
```

This `($size down)` and then `down` interests me most.
What is it?

Edit:

```
    $breakpoints: (
      xsmall: 0,
      small: 576px,
      medium: 768px,
      mediumlarge: 921px,
      large: 1200px,
      xlarge: 1420px,
      xxlarge: 1600px,
      wide: 1920px
    );
    $print-breakpoint: large;
    $breakpoint-classes: (xsmall small medium mediumlarge large xlarge xxlarge wide);
```

and the mixins:

```
    @mixin below($size) {
      @include breakpoint($size down) {
        @content
      }
    }

    @mixin above($size) {
      @include breakpoint($size) {
        @content
      }
    }
```

When I set `@include below(mediumlarge)` it actually goes UP a notch, to `large`, so when I want to make sure css is less than {medium} I need to call @include below(small)

What is this?

Comment: What does the mixin `breakpoint` look like?